# Тормозит форма после сворачивания

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день. Возникла довольно нелепая проблема. Есть форма с чартом, на чарт из другого потока выводится график, все отлично работает. Но стоит только свернуть форму, как после разворачивания начинаются жуткие тормоза приложения, график выводится еле еле, кнопки не прорисовываются.

Язык `с# .NET 4.0`

Comment: попробуй откатывать приложение до тех пор пока не будет тормозить что бы увидеть где проблема, ну и смотри что бы лишние потоки, соединения и т.д. были закрыты

Comment: Это в дебаг или релиз сборке? Если в дебаг - то наверняка откуда-то лезет туева хуча ексепшенов, но они кем-то гасяться.

Comment: Архив с примером в студию.

Comment: Возьмите dotTracer и посмотрите где проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь может быть несколько проблем. Первое, что приходит на ум, это то, что скорее всего происходит обращение к данной форме или её компонентам из разных потоков одного приложения. На такой случай стоит позаботиться о синхронизации потоков. Еще такие глюки могут возникать, если вы создаете компоненты( визуальные ) "на лету", т.е динамически. Правда в таком случае может возникнуть вторая ошибка - `EOSError 1400 Недопустимый дескриптор окна`.

Еще советую вам обновлять контекст устройства вывода после каждого рестора окна. Сделать это можно методом Refresh() или Repaint(), насколько точно помню...

Comment: Есть у меня такое смутное подозрение, что известный каждому программисту `EOSError 1400` не имеет никакого отношения к `.NET / WPF / WinForms`.

Comment: А еще у меня есть смутное подозрение, что @Чад ближе всех к истине.